# Site shows themeless and blockless front page

Tags: 8, blocks

I've installed a brand new Drupal 8 site (http://www.edcint.co.nz/tmp/drupal8_problem_new.PNG) with next to no configuration, default theme etc. I then ran Drupal Update against a Drupal 7 site (http://www.edcint.co.nz/tmp/drupal8_problem_existing.PNG). The content/users all came across but the front page shows without any theme or blocks, only the 3 articles/pages marked as "published to the front page" appear.

I've migrated another more simple Drupal 7 site to Drupal 8 and this did not happen.

Have I hit some limitation of the Upgrade module?
How can I make the theme and blocks reappear on the front page?

Comment: How was the front page implemented in Drupal 7? Is it a node? Panel page? Custom route from a module? Something else? How was it themed in the old site?

Comment: The frontpage is the default out-of-the-box Drupal 7 content feed. The old site was themed using Pixture Reloaded out-of-the-box. This fits under the "I've migrated another more simple Drupal 7 site to Drupal 8 and this did not happen." comment ie the other site I migrated was the same - default front page, Pixture Reloaded

Comment: Additionally, I just changed the source site to the Bartik theme and retried. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your watchdog logs (/admin/reports/dblog) after refreshing your homepage a few times.

This may give you some clues to what the problem is. For example...

I ran in to a similar issue with my D7 -> D8 migration, where my nodes were imported with a 'filtered_html' input_format. I was storing my node body content as markdown.

My front page had no blocks or theme. When I looked in my logs, I was seeing `Missing text format: filtered_html.`

I ran the following to update the input_format of my nodes, which fixed my problem.

`` UPDATE `node__body` SET `body_format`='full_html' WHERE `body_format`='filtered_html'; ``

To then get things displaying properly, I installed the markdown module (and one of the required libraries, I opted for commonmark).

`drush en markdown
composer require league/commonmark`

I then went to `/admin/config/content/formats/manage/full_html` and enabled markdown for that content type.

Comment: It would probably be best to create a new input format for markdown, and change the sql query to set the `body_format` to that.